# Using stringstream.fail() to check whether input is int or string

Tags: c++, string, input, int, stringstream

I'm creating a simple function printNode that takes in an int or the string "all", and prints a corresponding output. The int aspect of the function works well, but when I call

```
printNode all
```

the function prints "Error: invalid argument", and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
int main() {
    ...
    getline(cin, line)
    stringstream lineStream(line);
    stringstream elineStream(line);
    printNode(lineStream, elineStream);
    ...
}


int printNode(stringstream& lineStream, stringstream& elineStream) {
//String aspect of printNode
int nodeid;
string name;

// Parsing nodeid or name
lineStream >> nodeid;

// If parsing to nodeid fails, check if input is string "all"
if (lineStream.fail()) {
    elineStream >> name;
    if (elineStream.fail()) {
        if (elineStream.eof()) {
            cout << "Error: too few arguments" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Error: invalid argument" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if (name != "all") {
        cout << "Error: invalid argument" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    // Check for too many arguments
    elineStream >> ws; 
    if (!elineStream.eof()) {
        cout << "Error: too many arguments" << endl; 
        return 0;
    }

    // Print output for input "all" 
    cout << "Print: all nodes" << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: With a little more work you could make this a self-contained, compilable example.  Also, note that you should return 0 for success and 1 for failure--you're doing that backward.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Regarding the `1`/`0` for success/failure, why not just return a `bool`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: you're quite right!  I had mixed it up and read those returns as being from main().  They would be better as bool (or exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

You are giving it `printNode all` as input, while it expects only `all`. I tried your code and it works correctly (of course, giving it `printNode all` fails with invalid argument).

As a side note, you could have avoided using two streams simply by clearing the error flag on the first stream. That is, all your `elineStream` could have been just `lineStream` if you add `lineStream.clear();` after you see that it fails reading a number.

---

From your wording, I see something strange that I would also like to clarify (just in case):

> but when I call
>
> ```
> printNode all
> ```

By writing in the command line, you are not calling a function. The function is called when you write:

```
printNode(lineStream, elineStream);
```

in your source code. If in the command line you write `printNode all`, all of that string (since you read the whole line) would be transferred to the stream, not just `all`.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to get the "command" and all its options, by using [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to copy all words into a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Then it's just a simple check of the size of the vector to see if the command was legal or not.

Something line this:

```
std::vector<std::string> command_and_args;

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(lineStream),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::back_inserter(command_and_args));

if (command_and_args.size() == 0)
    std::cout << "Error: No command or arguments\n";
else if (command_and_args.size() == 1)
    std::cout << "Error: To few arguments\n";
else if (command_and_args.size() > 2)
    std::cout << "Error: To many arguments\n";
else
{
    // Got the command and one argument
    // Command in `command_and_args[0]`
    // Argument in `command_and_args[1]`
}
```

The `std::copy` part can be used for all commands, while the checks have to be individual.

---

**Edit:** Actually, checking of the number of arguments can be automatic too, if you create a structure detailing the commands (command string, boolean to tell if arguments are required, minimum number of arguments, maximum number of arguments, and a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) object for the command handler). The make a table with this structure, and go through it to find commands, check argument count (if needed) and then call the function object. Then the function object can check the individual arguments.